# SQL CASE WHEN Parameter is not empty

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have the following table:

```
-------------------------------------
groupid      value                   
-------------------------------------
A            10
A            15
B            20
C            50
```

Then I have one `parameter` called `@groupid`.
If parameter is `A`, then the result must select all the records. But If the parameter is not `A` then the result should only view the selected parameter.

Example, If the `parameter` is `B` then the result should be:

```
-------------------------------------
groupid      value                   
-------------------------------------
B            20
```

Example, If the `parameter` is `A` then the result should be:

```
-------------------------------------
groupid      value                   
-------------------------------------
A            10
A            15
B            20
C            50
```

Any idea?
Thank you.

Comment: It is not really very clear what you are saying here. can you explain a bit more?

Comment: @MEdwin, so if the parameter is 'A' then the result will show all the records. Then, if the parameter is not 'A' then the result will show only the selected parameter.

Comment: `CASE WHEN` is what you are looking for here.

Comment: Why don't you do the check in the client and execute one of two SQL statements?  They are quite different with different plans (probably).  By combining them you'll most likely get a plan optimised for one case but not the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my take with a mockup table, just change `@groupid` to any parameter `'A', 'B' or 'C'`:

```
declare @table table (groupId varchar(20), value int)
insert into @table
select 'A',            10 union all
select 'A',            15 union all
select 'B',            20 union all
select 'C',            50

declare @groupid varchar(2)='B'



    SELECT *
    FROM @table
    WHERE  
        'A'= @groupid 
        OR 
        groupid = @groupid;
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be the logic you want:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE @groupid = 'A' OR groupid = @groupid;
```

If the input is `'A'`, then all records match, otherwise the input only returns records whose `groupid` values match.

Answer (score 0):

This is highly counter intuitive, and I strongly advise against it. Nevertheless, you can use something like:

```
select groupid,value
from   tablename
where  @groupid = 'A'
    OR (@groupid <> 'A' AND @groupid = groupid)
```

A less confusing method would be:

```
select groupid,value
from   tablename
where  @groupid IS NULL
    OR @groupid = groupid
```